# Variable Length Needle in Haystack (Python)

Tags: python, pytest

I have a function designed to find errors in an application's search capabilities, which [generates a variable-length search string from the non-control UTF-8 possibilities](https://gist.github.com/3173004).  Running pytest iterations on this function, the random UTF-8 strings, submitted for search, generate debug errors roughly once per 500 searches.

As I can grab each of the strings that caused an error, I want to determine what is the minimal sub-series of the characters in those strings which truly provoke the error.  In other words, (inside of a pytest loop):

```
def fumble_towards_ecstasy(string_that_breaks):
    # iterate over both length and content of the string
        nugget = # minimum series of characters that break the search
        return nugget
```

Should I slice the string in half and whittle down each side and re-submit until it fails, choose random characters from its (len() - 1) and then back up if an error doesn't happen?  Brute force combinatorial?  What's the best way to step through this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Splitting the string in half will fail if there is a two character sequence that causes the failure, and that sequence lies exactly in the middle. Each half succeeds, but the combined string fails.

Here's one algorithm that will find a local minimum:

Try removing each character in turn.

- If removing the character still causes failure, keep the new shorter string and repeat the algorithm on this new string.
- If removing the character no longer causes failure, put it back and try removing the next character. Keep going until there are no more characters left to try. When you reach the end of the string you know that removing any one character causes the search to succeed.

Comment: Implemented this today.  Works great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a "whittle from both sides" approach.  Splitting the string will always run the risk of breaking up the substring that was causing the error.  My approach would be:

1. Pop as many characters off the left of the string as you can while still ensuring that the string causes an error.
2. Do the same to the right side.
3. You're left with - in theory - the minimal substring that causes the error.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I say minimal "in theory" because it's not guaranteed.  Say all strings of the form `.*A.*B.*` cause an error.  So given `abcAdefBghi`, this method will find `AdefB`, not the truly minimal `AB`.  But at least you know that the trigger(s) are on the far left and right sides.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's worth noting that the solution is possibly not unique, i.e. it may be the case that there are *two* or more broken substrings.

An alternate suggestion (to the good answers by both Xavier and Mark) is to run a recursive approach. Repeat the sampling with the limited subset of strings that caused the error. Once another error is found, repeat until a minimal substring is reached. This approach is robust enough to handle a more complex use case, where the error can exist in two non-adjacent entries. I don't think that is the case here, but it's nice to have a general purpopse method.